# Kendo v2014.3.1119 - Upload - getFiles is not a function

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-upload

I'm using Kendo UI v2014.3.1119

I could instantiate a kendo element:

```
$("#files").kendoUpload({
    async: {
        autoUpload: false
    }
    , multiple: false
});
```

However, when bind to a button event:

```
$('#uploadBtn').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var hey = $('#files').data('kendoUpload');

        console.log(hey.getFiles())
    });
```

I got the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: hey.getFiles is not a function
```

I followed the example from 
[here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/upload#methods-getFiles)

Not sure if this is a version issue or something I did incorrectly? Please help !

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getFiles() method, to retrieve selected files, was only implemented much later (in [Kendo UI R3 2016](https://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/kendo-ui/release-history/kendo-ui-r3-2016))

I would suggest you to update your kendo version. If you can't for some reason you can extend the kendoUpload component and implement for your. An approach to extend a component is described [here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/widget-basics/create-custom-kendo-widget).

André

Comment: Thanks. I have tried to use latest files from CDN and it worked